# How to use r curly brackets only for a part of an equation?

Tags: equations, align

So given the following MWE I wish to align the two equations i.e., the term `(A-B)` to be in alignment with the terms of `alpha` but I did not manage to do this with the right curly bracket being present only on top.

How can I manage to do so?

```
\begin{equation*}
 \left.
 \begin{aligned}
 \alpha = \  & (a + b + c) & \times \\
             & (f + g + h) & \times \\
             & (w + x + y) 
\end{aligned}\right\} \text{first part of eq} \\ 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    (A-B) % I want this to be aligned with the rest
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not the best way, but this works:

```
\[
  \begin{aligned}
    \alpha = \  & (a + b + c) & \times \\
                & (f + g + h) & \times \\
                & (w + x + y) & \\
                & (A-B)       &
   \end{aligned}
   \begin{aligned}
      \left.
      \begin{aligned}
          & \\
          & \\
          & \\
      \end{aligned}\right\} \text{first part of eq}\\
          &
   \end{aligned}
\]
```

It aligns the elements first and puts the brace later (in another align to match the size).
[image]